# Parse Json using Circe and monocle lens

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have written this sample code

```
package com.abhi
import io.circe._
import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._

object CirceTest extends App {
   val id = root.id.long
   val date = root.date.long

   val input =
      """
        |{
        |  "id" : 0,
        |  "childIds" : [
        |    11, 12, 13
        |  ],
        |  "date" : 1480815583505
        |}
      """.stripMargin
   parser.parse(input) match {
      case Left(a) => println(s"failed ${a}")
      case Right(json) =>
         val myId = id.getOption(json).get
         val myDate = date.getOption(json).get
         println(s"id: ${myId} date: ${myDate}")
   }
}
```

but this won't event compile

```
CirceTest.scala:26: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : scala.util.Right[A,B]
[error]  required: cats.data.Xor[io.circe.ParsingFailure,io.circe.Json]
[error]       case Right(json) =>
[error]            ^
```

I also tried

```
val jsonEither = parser.parse(input)
if (jsonEither.isRight) {
   val json = jsonEither.right.get
   val myId = id.getOption(json).get
   val myDate = date.getOption(json).get
   println(s"id: ${myId} date: ${myDate}")
}
```

but this also fails

```
[error] CirceTest.scala:27: value right is not a member of cats.data.Xor[io.circe.ParsingFailure,io.circe.Json]
[error]       val json = jsonEither.right.get
[error]                             ^
[error] one error found
```

I am pretty surprised. when I can do a `isRight` then why does compiler say that I can't do a `right`?

Here is my build.sbt file

```
name := "CirceTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.5.1",
   "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.5.1",
   "io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.5.1",
   "io.circe" %% "circe-optics" % "0.5.1"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Circe depends on the [Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) library, which recently removed `cats.data.Xor`, which was a right-biased `Either`-like type. Circe 0.5.0 and earlier versions used `cats.data.Xor` as the result type for parsing and decoding, but 0.6.0+ use the standard library's `Either`, since `Xor` is gone.

Updating your circe dependency to 0.6.1 will make your code work as written. If for some reason you're stuck on an earlier version of circe, you'll need to adjust your code to work with `Xor`. I'd suggest sticking to the most recent version, though—both circe and Cats are young projects and things are moving quickly. If you are stuck on an earlier version, and it's because of a library that depends on circe, please get in touch on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/circe/circe) and we'll try to work with the library maintainers to get things updated.